# Managing dockers on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I'm using dockers on a Windows server 2016, to run all sorts of Windows applications/tasks.

There are several solutions to manage dockers, such as swarm and marathon, but they don't work on Windows (or do work on Windows but via virtual box vm, which is problematic for my needs).

In the future mesos and dc/os will support Windows, but in the meanwhile,
is there an alternative that can work for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting up a **docker** container to manage the rest of your docker.

A couple containers which do exactly that:

- http://portainer.io/
- [DockerUI](https://github.com/kevana/ui-for-docker)

If you don't like that you could use a (local) gui to manage it, the only one I know of is:

- [simple-docker-ui](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-docker-ui/jfaelnolkgonnjdlkfokjadedkacbnib)